# Adding select boxes in each button click with options not selected in previous select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a add more field button by clicking which selectboxes are appended to a div.I want to make the select box options such that it is not selected in the previous select box.

my first select box

```
<select>
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Green</option>
<option value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

if I select red from select box 1 then
my dynamically generated second select box should be

```
<select>
<option value="2">Green</option>
<option value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

How can I do this?
My jquery to add more field

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function() {


   var max_fields      = 4; //maximum input boxes allowed
   var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
   var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

   var x = 1; 
     //initlal text box count


   $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click

       e.preventDefault();
       if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
           //text box increment

           $(wrapper).append('<div><select class="selectclass" name="targettype'+x+'" id="targettype'+x+'"></select><input type="text" name="quantity'+x+'" id="quantity'+x+'"  style="width:81%;"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
       appendOption(x);
   x++;
    }

   $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
       e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;

   })



    });


});

   </script>
```

Comment: You could originally have all 3 colors and hide the one that is the same as the one chosen

Comment: Checkboxes in this situation it is more convenient to use

Comment: Your question implies that all colours must be chosen, which seems the wrong use-case for `<select>` elements. I'd second the use of check-boxes, or some form of a sortable list.

Comment: @ Sanam Nath share a link on fiddle